# Changing image extension with javascript/jquery only?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm making a simple slider to show off artwork for a friend of mine. I'm really only familiar with javascript/jquery, so I'm not 100% comfortable using something else right now.

Since my friend doesn't have any programming knowledge, I'm trying to keep this really simple for her to update (i.e., automating creating new images whenever she adds a new one to the folder). She will upload images to a folder and will have to number them (i.e., 1.jpg, 2.jpg). My javascript uses a for loop to loop through numbers (she will have to update the loop whenever she adds a new image) and insert them into the file name. HOWEVER this limits her to only uploading one type of file. Is there someway to change the extension only using javascript?

This is what I have so far:

```
function callImages(){
    //create the image div
    $('.artslider').append('<div class="image"></div>');

    //create the files array
    var files = [];

    //start the loop, starting position will have to be updated as images are added
    for (i=8;i>=0;i--){

        //create the img src for a jpg img
        var imgJPG = 'arts/'+i+'.jpg';

        //find the natural width of the image after it loads to see if it actually exists
        var imgWidth = $('imgJPG').load().naturalWidth;

        //if the width is undefined, replace the jpg extension with gif
        if (imgWidth===undefined){
            var imgGIF = imgJPG.replace('jpg', 'gif');
            files[i] = '<img src="'+imgGIF+'" class="artsliderimg"/>';
        }

        //otherwise keep the jpg extension
        else {
            files[i] = '<img src="'+imgJPG+'" class="artsliderimg"/>';
        }

        //then add the images to the img div
        $('.image').append(files[i]);
    }
};
```

The problem with this if/else is that it will only create a gif image. If you switch the order, it will only create a jpg image.

edit: here's what this code produces: https://googledrive.com/host/0B1lNgklCWTGwV1N5cWNlNUJqMzg/index.html

Comment: Are you saying the problem with the if/else is that imgWidth is always undefined, and therefor gif is always used?

Comment: You aren't actually trying to change the physical file's extension right?

Comment: I think that might be the problem--since the images are created dynamically? But I'm not sure, and I'm not sure how to check.

Comment: Jack--no, just the file extension in the code. For example, the code should check to see if file 1.jpg exists. If it doesn't (because the folder contains 1.gif instead of 1.jpg), it should replace "jpg" with "gif". Ultimately, there would be nested if/else statements that check for other file types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with this bit of code:

```
var imgJPG = 'arts/'+i+'.jpg';
var imgWidth = $('imgJPG').load().naturalWidth;
```

`imgWidth` will always be undefined.

Firstly you are passing in the string 'imgJPG' instead of the parameter `imgJPG`. Secondly I think you have misunderstood jQuery selectors, this is used for selecting HTML elements, inputting a file path into here will not achieve anything. Thirdly I think you have misunderstood the `load` function, this is used for loading data from the server into a HTML element.

I would suggest using a function like below to check if the image exists:

```
function urlExists(url) {
  var http = jQuery.ajax({
    type:"HEAD",
    url: url,
    async: false
  });
  return http.status == 200;
}
```

Then in your code:

```
if (!urlExists(imgJPG)){
    var imgGIF = imgJPG.replace('jpg', 'gif');
    files[i] = '<img src="'+imgGIF+'" class="artsliderimg"/>';
}
else {
    files[i] = '<img src="'+imgJPG+'" class="artsliderimg"/>';
}
```